# How to use prepareForReuse

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

Can someone please show me how to use `prepareForReuse`? I read the documentation but I don't understand. I'm facing some weird behavior on my `tableView`.
In `tableviewCell` each row has 8 `collectionViewCell`. each cell has text except the last and second last cell, cells 7 and 8 having text with the image for some function calling.
but whenever I scrolled and clicked on the first image it calling both functions. it should call only its mapped function(first function) and it happens the same for the second image also.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.parentVC = self
    cell.index = indexPath.row
    if let val = arrData[indexPath.row] as? String{
        cell.textFieldValue.text = val.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    }
    if let val = arrData[indexPath.row] as? NSNumber{
        cell.textFieldValue.text = (val).stringValue.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    }
    
    cell.textFieldValue.isEditable = false
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    cell.textFieldValue.alignTextVertically()
    
    
    if((indexPath.row == 6) || (indexPath.row == 7)){
        cell.editButton.visibility = .visible
        cell.editButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 15.0).isActive = true
        cell.editButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 15.0).isActive = true
        if(indexPath.row == 6){
            cell.editButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "pencil-edit-button.png"), for: .normal)
            cell.editButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onCLickEditButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        }else if(indexPath.row == 7){
            cell.textFieldValue.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 2
            cell.textFieldValue.textContainer.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byTruncatingTail;
            cell.textFieldValue.alignTextVertically()
            cell.editButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "information.png"), for: .normal)
            cell.editButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onClickInfoButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
    }
    else{
        cell.textFieldValue.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 2
        cell.textFieldValue.textContainer.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byCharWrapping;
        cell.editButton.visibility = .gone
        cell.editButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0).isActive = true
        cell.editButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0).isActive = true
    }
    return cell
}
```

//CollectionViewCell

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITextViewDelegate  {

@IBOutlet weak var textFieldValue: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var editButton: UIButton!
var parentVC = UITableViewCell()
var index = Int()


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    textFieldValue.delegate = self
    
}
```

}

[image]
[image]

Comment: I dont think its the issue of cell reusability, So `prepareForReuse` might not help, your cell at index path 6 and 7 are right next to each other so whenever you scroll both the cells will be visible at the same time, so I dont think collection view will reuse the cell at index path 6 for 7 (obviously 6 is still visible how can it reuse it?) Even if it is for some reason reuse it you are already setting different selector so it cant call both the selectors simultaneously, some thing else is going wrong here

Comment: Each time you do an `if` (or switch which is the same), you need to do in the else, the reverse action. Meaning: Setting a `text`  => set it to nil. Changing a color? Reverse it in the else with a default color. Here, the nil text and default colors are the "default" value of your cell, that's the value you put in `prepareForResue()` if you don't want to write all the `else` cases.

Comment: @SandeepBhandari when the contentSize is not scrollable than the things working fine but when the contentSize is scrollable than the issue arriving. So I'm guessing the issue maybe related to the reusimg cell

Comment: At least consolidate `arrData` regarding String/Number while populating the data source array rather than in `cellForRow`, `Any` is the worst type choice for a data source

Answer (score 1):

The issue is a misunderstanding of "reuse."

Suppose you have a `UIView` in your cell (we'll call it `someView`), and your `cellForItemAt` func does this:

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {
    cell.someView.backgroundColor = .red
}
```

The first time a cell is dequeued for row 0, the view's background will be set to red.

Now we scroll a ways so that cell is **reused**... the background of `someView` will *still be red*.

So, generally, one would do this:

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {
    cell.someView.backgroundColor = .red
} else {
    cell.someView.backgroundColor = .white
}
```

What's happening with your code, is that you're not setting a **property** of the button -- you are ***adding*** an action.

So, each time the cell is reused, you are adding ***another*** action.

You could use `.removeTarget(...)` each time, before assigning a new target.

A better approach, though, would be to add the `.touchUpInside` action inside the cell class itself, and use either delegate/protocol pattern or (better) a closure in `cellForItemAt`.

As a side note, you are also repeatedly adding Width and Height constraints to the edit button each time the cell is reused. Since you're adding the *same* constraints each time, you probably won't hit an issue... but if the cell is reused, let's say 20 time, your button will have 20 sets of width/height constraints on it.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. setting width & height constraint to 0  is also not behave as expected. on scrolling, Visible image are also going invisible. as you can in my code i'm setting height & width constraint to 15 in `if` condition and setting 0 to in `else` condition. what is the problem now ? can you please help me

Comment: @SkSk - edit your question and include your cell class code. If you are laying it out as a Prototype cell in Storyboard, also add a screen cap of your layout (make sure you show the constraints expanded).

Answer (score 0):

`prepareForReuse` should only be used for resetting your cells state to the initial state.

The reuse of a cell is always going on like this:

1. `prepareForReuse` gets called by the `tableView` itself
2. cells config method gets called in `cellForRowAt`

**Example:**
We got a cell that is going to get reused for two cells in our tableView. The tableViewCell includes a label and an imageView. In this example we consider that we are not using the prepareForReuse function at all.

So we start by configuring cell no 1:

```
label.text = "cell 1"

imageView.image = UIImage(named: "exampleImage")
```

Your TableView attempts to reuse cell no 1 and create cell no 2:

```
label.text = "cell 2"
```

“We do not set the imageView for cell no 2”

**What happens now?**

Cell no 2 updates the text from the label to “cell 2” but shows the image from cell no 1 because the cell just got reused and we never nilled the imageView’s image out. If we use the function `prepareForReuse` and set:

```
imageView.image = nil
```

we are setting the `imageView`’s image to the initial state. If we would have a cell no 3 which is using an image again, first `prepareForReuse` is called by the tableView and than you call in your `cellForRowAt` function your configure method and the image gets set cleanly.

So in conclusion you should set everything you are configuring in your `cellForRowAt` function for your cell, back to the initial state in your `prepareForReuse` function to ensure clean reusing.